# How can I make a mobile app responsive for desktop?

Tags: responsive-design, web, desktop-application, grid, responsive

I am trying to make a desktop version of a mobile app. But not sure how to fill those full width cards to a desktop app.

[image]

[image: Web Page]

Comment: Are we working on the assumption that if there was more real estate to play with, you don't want to put more information on screen?

Comment: Can you share a mockup? We have nothing to see from your post.

Comment: @MikeM Added it.

Comment: These look more like tabs than cards. It looks fairly normal for tabs. It looks like normal behavior for a desktop app.

Comment: @MikeM I'm asking for how to put the matches inside tabs in mobile app. Tabs are not the problem, but the cards are.

Comment: okay, so sounds like you have a number of cards under each tab, right? On mobile the cards are full width, but your concern is the cards going full width, waayyy too wide for desktop. Right? Do you have a bootstrap style grid system you're working with?

Comment: @MikeM Yeah, exactly like that. Yes, I have a Semantic Grid System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the grid system to line the cards and set breakpoints.

Because you're using **[Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)**, you've got the tools right there. Instead of your cards flowing way too wide, add the right breakpoint. On desktop, you often see cards go three across. So in a 12 column grid, break it into 3 instances of 4 columns each.

Find a reasonable desktop breakpoint. I haven't used Semantic, but **[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)** generally has 3 breakpoints.

- Small devices (tablets): 768px and up
- Medium devices (desktops): 992px and up
- Large devices (large desktops) 1200px and up

There's also a 480px and lower, which applies to mobile phones.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4f86I.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm not sure what domain you're designing for, but **[mediaqueri.es](https://mediaqueri.es/)** has a gallery of responsive design inspiration; you'll see all manner of websites with their responsive breakpoints.

Comment: Do you think cards need dividers between?

Comment: I haven't seen dividers used. Normally you just have a subtle border containing each card. Dividers will just add more visual noise.

Comment: Also, there is an L or CS: GO icon every card. Where should I place it?

Comment: In the example above posted by @MikeM the Logo should be placed in the bottom on the left side of each card-title.